# Java AES Encryption with salt

Tags: java, encryption, aes, salt

Alright, turns out I suck at Encryption/Decryption. I just dont get it.
How can I make Java encrypt `String message1 = "hello world";` with `String salt = "mySalt";` using AES encryption? also how can I decrypt it once encrypted?

If you have the time to provide the most basic code, it would help me a lot.

Also 1 general question about AES encryption, using the same salt, will the same message always have the same encryption?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Java 256bit AES Encryption](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/992019/java-256bit-aes-encryption)

Comment: Something tells me you should probably not try to deploy any important software until you're a lot more at home with cryptography. AES is just a cipher, you still need to choose a *mode*, and a *key*, and some *initialization vector* scheme. Salts don't really have anything to do with encryption (rather with *hashing*).

Comment: Thilo, I saw that article, unfortunately I couldn't understand anything in it :S

Kerrek SB, I know, im just making for my own knowledge, experience.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

AES doesn't have a concept of a salt.  It just takes data, and a key.  For the same input, it will always generate the same output.

How you combine your message with your salt is up to you.  String concatenation is probably sufficient.  But note that salts don't really make a lot of sense for something like AES, because it's not a hash algorithm.

Comment: AES is just the cipher. The IV is part of the *mode* of operation.

Comment: Wait, now I'm very confused, so how can you encrypt a string which you will only be able to decrypt with a specific "password" or "key" or something?

Comment: @cody: Like I said, AES takes *data* and a *key*.

Comment: @cody: Well, I suppose you could call it a seed, yes.

Comment: Umm, ahh so confusing. So could you help me create the most basic code that will encrypt a simple message with a simple key? Please and Thank you :)

Comment: @cody: The code [here](http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/Security/AES/AES_v1.html) look reasonable (I'm not an expert in doing AES specifically in Java).  This code is generating a key for you, put you could always save that, or replace it with your own.

Comment: @Oli Charlesworth Alright thanks, btw, you said that seed in AES doesn't make sense, what HASH encryption can I use in java that allows me to reverse with a key?

Comment: @cody: I said that a *salt* doesn't make sense for AES.  And you can't reverse a hash; that's the whole point!

Comment: @oli charlesworth oh, lol (i suck at this) well thanks for your help, im just looking at the code you sent me and im trying to make it use a static salt, just not 100% sure where the key is.

Answer (score 6):

With Spring Security Crypto, it is simplified (mainly because they default to the password based encryption rather than other forms):

```
final String password = "A private password that you need to keep secret.";  
final String salt = KeyGenerators.string().generateKey();
TextEncryptor encryptor = Encryptors.text(password, salt);

String cipherText = encryptor.encrypt(textToEncrypt);

String decryptedText = encryptor.decrypt(cipherText);
```

AES is just a cipher, and you can use an IV with the text you are encrypting.
With symmetric encryption, the salt is used for the key/secret that you encrypt with, as you can see above.

In the real world you will have to deal with distributed systems, shared keys and salts across the cluster, etc, etc. Lots of fun.

Spring Security is a thin abstraction over JCE, so it's easy to adapt if you don't use Spring itself.

Comment: I find this solution elegant if you want to quickly implement an encryption system.

Answer (score 5):

Always salt your AES files. The reason for this is say you have a directory of JPEG files that are cipher encrypted with the same password but don't have a salt. If somebody gets hold of those files they will see all the files start with the same bytes (as that is the JPEG header and the same passphrase will be always encrypt to the same values until the bytes start to differ, at least with a CBC), they will also know what the first blocks of the file will look like unencrypted. Even if they don't know what type of files they are, they can probably guess the type from the length of the lead in that are similar and the various file formats out there.

Knowing this, they can reverse engineer your password in a manner similar to rainbow tables/brute force. Salting won't stop this happening, but will make it really hard to crack as every file (after the salt) will be different so file type identification is difficult, plus they would have to generate a rainbow table for each salt or the computational overhead of creating an Initialization Vector for the salt.

OpenSSL stores the salt in the file

e.g. I created a file using this command with a password of 'password':
**echo "randomprhase" | openssl aes-128-cbc -out message.enc**
Here is the hexdump of the resulting file:-

> [james@web openssltest]$ hexdump message.enc
> 0000000 **6153 746c 6465 5f5f** 7eaa c4fd 63d8 8c8c
> 0000010 9519 75c9 0497 d449 27f5 2c91 0d34 5ceb
> 0000020

And the same data when I ran the encryption again:-

> [james@web openssltest]$ hexdump message1.enc
> 0000000 **6153 746c 6465 5f5f** a876 5394 53f1 bf1a
> 0000010 adcb e1cd dba9 8034 cf13 8b3f c37c 5048
> 0000020

The first 4 bytes say that the file is salted (**6153 746c 6465 5f5f**) and will always be the same.

The next 4 bytes is the random salt (**7eaa c4fd 63d8 8c8 for first file** & **a876 5394 53f1 bf1a** for the second file)
OpenSSL will take this salt and build the Initialization Vector (IV), being an MD5 hash of the password + salt repeated 3 times. This IV is then used to encrypt the file.
Note the payload of the last 8 bytes in each case is different.

If we ran the same command while not salting:

[james@web openssltest]$ echo "randomprhase" | openssl aes-128-cbc -nosalt -out nosalt.enc

[james@web openssltest]$ echo "randomprhase" | openssl aes-128-cbc -nosalt -out nosalt1.enc

> [james@web openssltest]$ hexdump nosalt.enc
> 0000000 947e f4ab 6dd7 c548 89e4 b587 82f4 5136
> 0000010
>
> [james@web openssltest]$ hexdump nosalt1.enc
> 0000000 947e f4ab 6dd7 c548 89e4 b587 82f4 5136
> 0000010

Notice that when I repeated it using the same password and specified not to salt the payloads are identical.

In a Java implementation you can store your salt separately but worth spending your time writing something that emulates the OpenSSL implementation so you don't have to rely on your own code to decrypt a file (especially if you lose your code at some point in the future, encryption can thwart you as much as it can thwart an attacker).

Answer (score 1):

When you use AES with a salt value, salt value differs from the text to encrypt - but the key remains the same - in that case you need to also store the salt value as well..

[Here](http://www.digizol.com/2009/10/java-encrypt-decrypt-jce-salt.html) is a good example...

Comment: Yah, I saw that, but I couldnt even get it to run, it compiled with 2 warnings (which is fine for that code since it uses Sun packages) but I couldn't get it to run, something about package not found ... :S

Comment: Its just encryption/decryption with normal AES - nothing new - you just need to add a salt value and make sure you store it for decryption.