# Migrate openssl to java

Tags: java, c++, openssl, bouncycastle

I need to migrate a crypto package from C++/openssl to pure java implementation. However, I am having some issues that I don't know how to solve.

Below is a C++ list that outlines a decryption scheme that I am currently trying to migrate.

```
#include <openssl/evp.h>
#include <openssl/aes.h>
#include <openssl/rand.h>
#include <openssl/bio.h>
#include <openssl/buffer.h>

// set master key
AES_KEY master_key; 
const int AES128_KEY_SIZE = 16;
unsigned char* master_secret = "averysecretmastersecret"; 
AES_set_encrypt_key(master_secret, AES128_KEY_SIZE * 8 , &master_key);

// Base64 decode; encryptedInput is the original input text
// b64_output consists of two parts: a leading salt (16 bytes) and the following actual data
char* b64_output = base64Decode(encryptedInput); // base64Decode(const char* encodedText) -> char* decodedText

// prepare salt
const char SALT_LEN = 16; // first byte is reserved. Actually only use 15 bytes = 120 bit
unsigned char salt[SALT_LEN]; 
memcpy(salt, b64_output, SALT_LEN); // read salt

// generate key
const int AES128_KEY_SIZE = 16;
unsigned char key[AES128_KEY_SIZE];
salt[0] = 1; //
AES_ecb_encrypt(salt, key, &master_key, AES_ENCRYPT);

// generate iv
const int AES128_IV_SIZE = 16;
unsigned char iv[AES128_IV_SIZE];
salt[0] = 2; // ensure that key and iv are different
AES_ecb_encrypt(salt, iv, &master_key, AES_ENCRYPT);

// initialize cipher context
EVP_CIPHER_CTX *de;
de = EVP_CIPHER_CTX_new();
EVP_CIPHER_CTX_init(de);
EVP_DecryptInit_ex(de, EVP_aes_128_cbc(), NULL, key, iv)

aes_decrypt(b64_output + SALT_LEN, length - SALT_LEN);

// plaintext is a buffer to contain the output
int plaintext_size = DEFAULT_BUFFER_SIZE;
char *plaintext = (char*)malloc(plaintext_size);
int aes_decrypt(const char *ciphertext, int len)
{
    int p_len = len, f_len = 0;
    // allocate an extra cipher block size of memory because padding is ON
    //  #define AES_BLOCK_SIZE 16
    if(p_len + AES_BLOCK_SIZE > plaintext_size) {
        ASSERT_CALL(enlarge_buffer(plaintext, plaintext_size, p_len + AES_BLOCK_SIZE), "enlarge plaintext buffer failed");
    }

    ASSERT_OPENSSL( EVP_DecryptInit_ex(de, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL), "sets up decode context failed");
    ASSERT_OPENSSL( EVP_DecryptUpdate(de, (unsigned char*)plaintext, &p_len, (unsigned char*)ciphertext, len), "decrypt failed");
    EVP_DecryptFinal_ex(de, (unsigned char*)plaintext+p_len, &f_len);
    return EY_SUCCESS;
}

EVP_CIPHER_CTX_free(de); 
dec_result = std::string(plaintext);
```

Below is a java code list that I currently have (not working, of course) to reproduce above C++ logic:

```
String encrypted = "AtUKTnCF18kFTJIycg/RXKJ82IVCtaa+eKNVl8FhT0k+wvpc+cBIs5jb/QlLRMf4";

String secret = "averysecretmastersecret";

int SALT_LEN = 16;
String keyAlgorithm = "AES";
String ECB_TRANSFORM = "AES/ECB/NoPadding";
String CBC_TRANSFORM = "AES/CBC/NoPadding";

byte[] bytesOfSecret = Arrays.copyOf(secret.getBytes(), 16);
Key key =new SecretKeySpec(bytesOfSecret, keyAlgorithm);
Cipher ecbCipher = Cipher.getInstance(ECB_TRANSFORM);
Cipher cbcCipher = Cipher.getInstance(CBC_TRANSFORM);

// decode
byte[] decoded = Base64.getDecoder().decode(encrypted);

byte[] salt = Arrays.copyOf(decoded, SALT_LEN);
byte[] data = Arrays.copyOfRange(decoded, SALT_LEN, decoded.length);

// get iv
salt[0] = 2;
ecbCipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key);
byte[] iv = ecbCipher.doFinal(salt);
iv = Arrays.copyOf(iv, 16);

AlgorithmParameterSpec parameterSpec = new IvParameterSpec(iv);

cbcCipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, key, parameterSpec);
byte[] bytes = cbcCipher.doFinal(data);
String decrypted = new String(bytes);

System.out.println(decrypted);
```

There are a couple places that I don't know how to map from C++ to java right now. First, in the C++ code, it uses a salt to generate a key and an iv, which are subsequently used to initialize EVP cipher context as in `EVP_DecryptInit_ex(de, EVP_aes_128_cbc(), NULL, key, iv)`. I don't know the equivalent operation in java.

Second, there is no direct mentioning in the C++ code whether padding is used. I tried both NoPadding and PKCS5Padding, but not sure which one is the right one.

So, how can I reproduce the C++ logic in java? Is there any example out there?

**update**
I also tried BouncyCastle. It is still not working. Below is my code:

```
int SALT_LEN = 16;

String encrypted = "AtUKTnCF18kFTJIycg/RXKJ82IVCtaa+eKNVl8FhT0k+wvpc+cBIs5jb/QlLRMf4";
String password = "averysecretmastersecret";

// decode
byte[] decoded = Base64.getDecoder().decode(encrypted);
byte[] salt = Arrays.copyOf(decoded, SALT_LEN);
byte[] data = Arrays.copyOfRange(decoded, SALT_LEN, decoded.length);

BufferedBlockCipher cipher = new PaddedBufferedBlockCipher(new CBCBlockCipher(new AESEngine()));

PBEParametersGenerator generator = new OpenSSLPBEParametersGenerator();
byte[] bytesOfSecret = PBEParametersGenerator.PKCS5PasswordToBytes(password.toCharArray());
generator.init(bytesOfSecret, salt, 1);

ParametersWithIV parametersWithIV = (ParametersWithIV) generator.generateDerivedParameters(128, 128);

// for decryption
cipher.init(false, parametersWithIV);

byte[] decrypted = new byte[cipher.getOutputSize(data.length)];
System.out.println("expected decrypted size = " + decrypted.length); // prints ... size = 32

int processedBytes = cipher.processBytes(data, 0, data.length, decrypted, 0);
System.out.println("processed bytes = " + processedBytes); // prints ... bytes = 16

cipher.doFinal(decrypted, processedBytes); // Line 59, run into exception

String output = new String(decrypted);

System.out.println(output);
```

Line 59, as marked above, gives this exception:

```
org.bouncycastle.crypto.InvalidCipherTextException: pad block corrupted
    at org.bouncycastle.crypto.paddings.PKCS7Padding.padCount(Unknown Source)
    at org.bouncycastle.crypto.paddings.PaddedBufferedBlockCipher.doFinal(Unknown Source)
...
```

Comment: I suspect `EVP_DecryptInit_ex` is another method you need to migrate.

Comment: You really aren't migrating anything here. You're writing equivalent code in a completely different API.

Answer (score 1):

This is an example of java AES encryption i hope this helps

```
      String key = "HkJHBKJBvffdbv";
      String IV= "qjfghftrsbdghzir";
      String theMessageToCifer ="your message";

      SecretKeySpec secretKeySpec = new SecretKeySpec(key.getBytes(), "AES");

      IvParameterSpec ivSpec = new IvParameterSpec(IV.getBytes());
      try{

      //specify your mode
      Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CTR/NoPadding");
      cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, secretKeySpec,ivSpec);

      encrypted = cipher.doFinal(theMessageToCifer.getBytes());

      bytesEncoded = Base64.encode(encrypted);
      System.out.println(" base64 code " +bytesEncoded);
      System.out.println("encrypted string: " +encrypted);
      // decryption
      cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, secretKeySpec,ivSpec);
      byte[] original = cipher.doFinal(encrypted);
      String originalString = new String(original);
      System.out.println("Original string: " + originalString );
      }catch (Exception e){
         e.printStackTrace();
      }
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. However, I am afraid this doesn't help much. One gap between your example and the C++ example in my post is that the iv is predefined in your example, whereas the iv is derived from the salt in the C++ code. Another gap is that the salt also produces a so-called key parameter in the C++ example, which has no place in your java example.

Comment: There is a question here on stackoverflow talking about salt in AES using java i guess you should take a look it might help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7303103/java-aes-encryption-with-salt